# rails: undefined method hmtl_safe with simple form and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, simple-form

I have a rails app using simple form and devise gems, and i recently updated my gems but i had the following issue, for new user session form i had `undefined method 'html_safe' for #<Hash:0x0056223f885c68>` error message for password field, before it was working just fine.

I also tried input field_field instead of input, and in this case it worked just fine but the render result looked messy, so i added wrapper to make it look better but i had again the error message. i have this issue only with new user session, new user registration works fine.

here's my view:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :login, autofocus: true, placeholder: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, placeholder: true %>
    <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-md-6">
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Login", :class => 'pull-right' %>
  </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `placeholder` have a string to display instead of being a boolean? EG: `placeholder: "password"`

Comment: No. with simple form you can put the value to true and simple form will look for the value with key  `password` in translation file

Comment: Have you edited your translations, so that the password/placeholder key now has a nested set of values?

Comment: I always use translations files in rails app. For simple form i just followed the examples in the github page I18n section.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, i just put this code:

`<%= f.input_field :password, placeholder: true, class: "form-control" %>`

But is still don't understand why input and wrapper is not working for password field and only with new session